# How to create a MSBuild Target that will only run if necessary

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I have been experimenting with MSBuild to create custom targets. I am currently attempting to add support for compiling file with the JAWS script compiler. This is what I have so far.

## Scripts.props

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DEVDOCS_DIR>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\..\..\..\DevDocs'))</DEVDOCS_DIR>
        <BUILTIN_MASTER>$(DEVDOCS_DIR)\jsd\enu\builtin_master.jsd</BUILTIN_MASTER>
        <TOOLBOX_DIR>$(DEVDOCS_DIR)\Toolbox</TOOLBOX_DIR>
        <JAWS_VER>17.0</JAWS_VER>
        <!-- If perl.exe is not in your path, set the following variable to the full path and file name of perl.exe.
        Optionally you could set the PERL_EXE environment variable. -->
        <PERL_EXE Condition="'$(PERL_EXE)'==''">perl.exe</PERL_EXE>
        <!-- If scompile.exe is not in your path, set the following variable to the full path and file name of scompile.exe.
        Optionally you could set the SCOMPILE_EXE environment variable. -->
        <SCOMPILE_EXE Condition="'$(SCOMPILE_EXE)'==''">scompile.exe</SCOMPILE_EXE>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

## Scripts.targets

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="GenerateBuiltinJSD">
        <Exec Command="&quot;$(PERL_EXE)&quot; compilejsd.pl -v Jaws/$(JAWS_VER) -o &quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\builtin.jsd&quot; &quot;$(BUILTIN_MASTER)&quot;" WorkingDirectory="$(TOOLBOX_DIR)" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="CompileScripts">
        <Exec Command="&quot;$(SCOMPILE_EXE)&quot; /d &quot;%(ScriptSourceFiles.FullPath)&quot;" Outputs="%(ScriptSourceFiles.RootDir)%(ScriptSourceFiles.Directory)%(ScriptSourceFiles.Filename).jsb" WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="Clean">
        <ItemGroup>
            <JSBFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\*.jsb" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Delete Files="@(JSBFiles)" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="Build">
        <CallTarget Targets="GenerateBuiltinJSD;CompileScripts" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

## Scripts.vcxproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ScriptSourceFiles Include="Default.jss" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ScriptMessageFiles Include="Default.jsm" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ScriptHeaderFiles Include="HJConst.jsh" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ScriptDocumentationFiles Include="default.jsd" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{B2C4363D-D228-425D-AB04-38997EA229C0}</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration">
    <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="Scripts.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Scripts.targets" />
</Project>
```

This works up to a point. The problem is that when I do a build, it rebuilds all the script files, even if the relevant source file has not changed.

My question is how can I modify this so that each file is only built if necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are asking about is called [Incremental Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx), and hopefully it is supported by MSBuild utility. All you have to do is to specify inputs and outputs for a target you are planning to skip if no source files are changed.

> To specify inputs and outputs for a target: Use the Inputs and Outputs attributes of the Target element. For example:

```
<Target Name="Build"
    Inputs="@(CSFile)"
    Outputs="hello.exe">
```

> MSBuild can compare the timestamps of the input files with the timestamps of the output files and determine whether to skip, build, or partially rebuild a target.

To succeed in your task you have to properly generate the **Inputs** and **Outputs** of your target. This can be achieved by using special targets, which will populate the required items, or you can use the transformation explicitly:

```
<Target Name="CompileScripts"
        Inputs="@(ScriptSourceFiles)"
        Outputs="@(ScriptSourceFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(FileName).jsb')">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(SCOMPILE_EXE)&quot; /d &quot;%(ScriptSourceFiles.FullPath)&quot;" Outputs="%(ScriptSourceFiles.RootDir)%(ScriptSourceFiles.Directory)%(ScriptSourceFiles.Filename).jsb" WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
</Target>
```

(Also note that instead of referencing `%(RootDir)` item metadata you should use `$(OutDir)` property, because it is more straightforward, but you should ensure that this property is specified and exists when the target is executed).